# Redirecting grep output to file

Tags: bash, shell

If I execute

```
$ java -jar selenium-server.jar 2>&1 | grep "jetty.Server"
```

I get, after a while, the output I expect:

```
$ 16:30:24.881 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@6b0a2d64
```

But I i try to redirect grep output to a file, it doesn't write a thing

```
$ java -jar selenium-server.jar 2>&1 | grep "jetty.Server" > /tmp/ebook_selenium
```

Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Do you see the output after the java process exits?  Just a guess, but maybe grep is flushing its output when it writes to `stdout` but not to a file.  Edit: you can test this by using `grep --line-buffered` to force grep to output each line as it's processed.

Comment: nope, it doesn't write a thing

Comment: but your guess is right, -line-buffered solved the problem. thanks for showing me the right direction.

Comment: @AdamLiss: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We found that `grep` flushes its output when it writes to `stdout` but not to a file.

`grep --line-buffered` will force grep to output each line as it's processed.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem with redirecting top output to a file :D